# Installing atom packages with dependencies whilst offline

Tags: atom-editor, dependency-management, offline

I've just joined a new office and their security is *very* tight. Essentially, we cannot go online without connecting to another machine. This means any applications that attempt to connect online won't connect to anything.

I'm trying to set up atom for python development (I've not used atom before and it's all that available to me!) - but the lack of internet is causing an issue.

I understand that to install a package, I can download it from github, and extract it to ~/.atom/packages - and this works! But what do I do with packages with dependencies that haven't been downloaded? Is there a simple way to get the package and the dependency whilst being offline?

I've also noticed that although my office has atom installed there's no 'apm' or 'npm' commands in the terminal...is this common?

thanks

Comment: Related, maybe a duplicate: [How can I manually download packages for atom editor and install them (manually)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39081968/4518341)

Comment: Take a look at [portable-packages](https://atom.io/packages/portable-packages), it creates portable archives of the packages installed at home