# Atom editor: Keybinding to move cursor to the next (or previous) function definition

Tags: python, atom-editor

When navigating a single file in Atom editor, is there a keybinding to “jump to the next (or previous) definition or function”?

In Lisp editing, this is called structural editing, where a keybinding traverses to what is called the next (or previous) top-level form.

For something like Python, jumping to the start of line by tab indentation level would be ideal.

I am not looking for **go-to** behavior because I do not want to recall the function name. I just want to navigate my file by “jumping” to the next (or previous) function.

Answer (score 0):

The best I could find (for now) is `jump-lines` package: https://github.com/ozamarripa/jump-lines

Atom packages can be installed with these steps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39941440/4903731